# Simultaneous gestures iOS don't work as expected

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer, simultaneous

I'm trying to implement a simultaneous two-finger left swipe and two-finger right-swipe.

In my viewDidLoad, I initialize the gestures as follows:

```
swipeRecognizerL= [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]
                       initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeL)];
swipeRecognizerL.direction=UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
swipeRecognizerL.numberOfTouchesRequired=2;
swipeRecognizerL.delegate = self;


swipeRecognizerR= [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]
                       initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeR)];
swipeRecognizerR.direction=UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
swipeRecognizerR.numberOfTouchesRequired=2;
swipeRecognizerR.delegate = self;
```

I then add the recognizers to an AVPlayerViewController;

```
AVPlayerViewController *controller = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc]init];
[controller.view.subviews[0] addGestureRecognizer:swipeRecognizerR];
[controller.view.subviews[0] addGestureRecognizer:swipeRecognizerL];
```

The delegate methods look like this:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer{
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer{

    NSLog(@"This one:%@,  theOtherOne:%@", gestureRecognizer, otherGestureRecognizer);
    return YES;
}
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch{
    return YES;
}
```

Now, individual two-finger swipes are recognized OK, but when I do a double two-finger swipe (one left, one right), somehow, it seems to be interpreted as a pinch gesture, as per the logging in *shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer* :

> This one:; target= <(action=handleSwipeR,
>   target=)>; numberOfTouchesRequired = 2;
>   direction = right>,  theOtherOne:; target=
>   <(action=_handlePinchGesture:, target=)>>

Any clue what I'm doing wrong? Let me know if you need additional information.

Comment: so you want to recognize 4 fingers at once, 2 fingers each going opposite directions? 

Yes, that will be considered an outward pinch. I do not think there is a way to have the swipes both recognized at the same time as far as the built in methods. 

Why not use pinch and check for directionality in your selector target?

Comment: @solenoid: A pinch is not expressed as a 4-finger gesture. But I can imagine that it is hard to distinguish which finger belongs to what specific gesture. In the mean time I try to understand your suggestion. 'check for directionality'?

Comment: I am also kind of confused about 2 things: how a pinch gesture is in there in the first place in your logs, do you have a pinch gesture? If you do, and you let it always recognize with any other gesture, try changing the order they are added to the view OR specifically call out what gestures return true to work together.  The thing I was mentioning before  is basically making a custom gesture.